# Plugin from cordova don't be recognize

Tags: android, node.js, html, cordova

I've create a cordova project, install nodejs, cordova, etc
I use the CLI methods.

To add a plugin  I use :

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs
```

In my HTML :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  navigator.notification.beep(1);
}
```

In my config.xml :

```
  <feature name="Notification">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
  </feature>
```

I've this in the Android Studio console

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'beep' of undefined"
```

I've added the media plugin with the same problem but the vibrate plugin works well.

Comment: Do you have the `android.permission.VIBRATE` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`? Also, is `cordova.js` included in your HTML file?

Comment: Yes, I have the vibrate permission but my problem is with the dialogs plugin.